# How to add custom css to section in shopify

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add a custom css to my shopify section. I have created a css file in asset folder called test2.css:

```
.body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: blue;
}

.h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

And on top of my liquid file I have added this code:

```
<div class="page-width {{ section.settings.section_css_class }}">
```

And below in the liquid file:

```
{

"type": "text",
    "id": "section_css_class",
    "label": {
      "en": "Section CSS Class"
    },
    "default": {
      "en": "Type your own CSS class"
    }
  },
```

In my section I got this input box:

[image]

I have followed this guide:

https://www.ecommercethesis.com/how-to-add-css-class-to-a-section-in-shopify/

But it doesn’t work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the markup. Does shopify really have elements with `class="body"` and `class="h1"` (only such elements would be affected by the CSS you've shown)?

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with the css. I just want to change the background color of the section.

Comment: I don't think the link you have posted has anything to do with CSS classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom CSS file to the section in shopify simply just add this at the very top of the section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'test2.css' | asset_url }}">
```